# Determine which Rails version I'm using when using Railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, railtie

Stupid question:

I'm using Railties version 3.2.3 and wish to check which version of Rails its running exactly (what with the recent number of security issues). I've looked into the gem's code but can't seem to get a handle on it. Perhaps I'm being stupid and the rails version matches that of realties?

Either way I'd appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails::VERSION::STRING` returns the currently running version of Rails when used within your app.